# Selection with circle using JSTS

Tags: javascript, openlayers, draw-interaction

Anybody know if there is a possibility of using JSTS library with OL3, to create a circle for selecting marker in a map.

Actually i succeed creating a polygon which can select markers and return the name of the markers, but when i try to do the same with a circle it's not working. 
I can't find anywhere something helpful or an equivalent function of "PolyIntersectsPoly"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch your draw circle to a proper polygon using the `ol.geom.Polygon.fromCircle`  api doc [here](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.1/apidoc/ol.geom.Polygon.html). In that way jsts can understand the polygon and perform the intersection.

Check the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dad1w7ef/) to see it in action.